# Scroll on duplicated Layout - Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Here I am using this code to paste my main_activity.xml on top of itself 5 times, making a long list of itself

Here is my code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
   LayoutInflater loiViewInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
   getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   View mView = loiViewInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, 
   null);
   FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new 
   FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
   ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   params.setMargins(0,i * 400,0,0);
   addContentView(mView, params);
}
```

Everything works handy dandy, but how can I make it to where I can scroll down?
The activities go off the screen and I can't think of a way to scroll down. Is it possible?

Thanks, Cooper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html), just set some container, like a linear layout, and copy your layout inside.

The hierarchy should look like:

```
ScrollView
    LinearLayout
        YourCopy
        YourCopy
        YourCopy
```

For instance, for your container view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/list_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

And on your loop (once you set your layout above with setContentView) something like:

```
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)findById(R.id.list_container)
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

   // inflate and set up your layout mView
   // (...)

   container.addView(mView);
}
```

Basically, you are injecting your copies inside the LinearLayout (which is inside the ScrollView).

Comment: I somewhat get that, but I am unsure how to do this because I am setting the view inside the Java, not XML. Could I get some example code? If that isn't to much to ask?

Comment: Thank you! Works perfect, just what I wanted. + Upvote, + Answered.

Answer (score 0):

As Logain suggested, you can use a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) and copy your layouts inside.Here is a sample.

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/start_root"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/page_title_text"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_intro"
            style="@style/wizard_intro_style"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fragment_title" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```